# jq - How to filter out an object with multiple integers

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to filter out arrays that don't contain the number '32' but it only filters out those that contain just one integer.

```
{
  "tags": [
    21
  ]
}
{
  "tags": [
    32
  ]
}
{
  "tags": [
    21,
    32
  ]
}
```

But upon running:

```
select(.tags[] == 32 | not)
```

I still get one array containing 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is looking for tags which has only one value 32.

This should do the job:

```
select(.tags | contains([32]) | not)
```